# contenteditable div - wrap text in span and style it without affecting newly added text

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm making a tags component using Angular 6. In my component, the user will add a bunch of strings separated by commas and when they blur out of the input, the tags will be wrapped by a span so that I can style it `<span class="item"> tag </span>`.

When the user focuses out of the input, the commas should be hidden as well. For that, on blur, I wrap the commas in another span `<span class="comma">,</span>` to be able to style it.

So what I was thinking was to simply set a style for the "comma" class:

```
.comma {
 opacity: 0;
}
```

The problem with this is, that whatever text I type after a committed comma (one that's wrapped by the comma span) would  also have the `opacity:0` applied until I focus out of the input and the tag span gets wrapped around the text.

This is all that's expected from the component:

1. User will add several tags separated by commas
2. When user focuses out, all the tags will get wrapped by a styled span and the commas will be hidden.
3. The user can add new strings separated by commas to the end of the committed tags and can focus out to commit the new tags.

This is a fiddle where I don't hide the comma but instead color it so that you can see the newly added text will also have the same style as the comma:
https://jsfiddle.net/daek1sgz/3/

To re-create:

1. Add a comma (,) after tag2 and focus out of the input box.
2. Observe the tags and comma is now styled
3. Focus on the input again and type text after the last comma.
4. Observe that the text background is pink, same as the comma.

Expected outcome:
The new text not to have any styles.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we focus out, you can convert string to array using javascript split(',') method. Then, you can use *ngFor Directive to display the array item inside SPAN tag.

### User Input :

Let's say, user enters xx,yy,zz as input to the Text field. On (blur) event, you can read the input value and convert to array.

Component :
-----------                                                                    `const tags = input.split(',');`
                                                                                     Now you can use this tags property in the template file and display using *ngFor structural Directive.

Template:
---------                                                                                                   `<div *ngFor="let item of tags" ><span>{{item}}</span></div>`

Comment: Hi. Thank you!! I used your idea and came up with a easier solution than what I had. Can you add more details to your answer? Maybe an example. I'll mark it as the answer. :)